# How much data should I read into RAM at one time?

Tags: performance

I'm writing a program that reads a file, performs operations on every byte,and then writes it to another file. In order to conserve memory on larger files, I do this a little bit at a time, with a clear performance hit. How much would be a good size to read into RAM? Right now I arbitrary have the default set to 1 Megabyte. But the more I do at one time, the faster my program is.

The real question im asking here is how much RAM usage would be considered greedy for one program to use?

Comment: One meg doesn't sound too unreasonable. One thought - can you thread off the reading/writing and use multiple 1MB buffer instances so that the reading and writing I/O can proceed in parallel with the byte-processing?

Comment: What's stopping you figuring this out for yourself ? You've got everything you need to calculate a good answer, all we've got is a vague description of a sort of issue. This is a really bad sort of question to ask on SO.

Comment: why are you processing constant equally-sized chunks anyway? why not determine the size of the chunk to process based on the currently available amount of memory?